# How to access a value of another object in an array in javasript

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I need to access the value of another object in an array in javascript. I am using react table, i need to send the id of the row when the name field is clicked.

```
 const columns = React.useMemo(
    () => [
        {
            Header: "Sl.No",
            accessor: "id",

        },
        {
            Header: "Name",
            accessor: "name",
            Cell: ({ cell: { value } }) => (
                
                <Link to={`/category/${value}`}>{value}</Link>
                
                // <Link to={`/suppliers/`}>
                //     {value}
                // </Link>
               
            )
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a `props.row.id` that you can use there

```js
Cell: (props) => {
  const value = props.row.id
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i got it fix

```
    {
            Header: "Name",
            accessor: "name",
            Cell: ({row}) => (
          
                <Link to={`/inventory/category/${row.original.id}`}> 
                 {row.original.name}</Link>
               
            )
        },
```